# Blockchain API/web socket is still available?

Tags: laravel, blockchain, blockchain.info-api

I have received a turn over laravel project to me,..
and it has function to receive BTC payments by scanning their blockchain address/QR code.
the function was working last 6 months,..
but now is not work,...
 do you have idea that blockchain api/web socket has been updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you have not shown us how you implemented the receive payment option in your project.
you may be using a deprecated version of the receive payments API.

the new version can be found here https://www.blockchain.com/api/api_receive.

you will now need a new API key and an xPub key. you can request the new API key here https://api.blockchain.info/v2/apikey/request/.

Comment: Sorry for not showing it because its confidential, thanks so much that is nice,.. but i try another payment method trough blockchain websocket api. i found toturials in here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=55xvr2oqMdk

Comment: Then it is very hard for us to really help. I hope you were able to solve it otherwise look out at https://packagist.org and https://packalyst.com

You may get some useful packages that will help you.